# how to pass props into link functions?

Tags: javascript, function

in case i have init function with event listeners, what have inside link to function with console.log(). The problem is, i need to pass props, into this function. How i can do that. With this example what i write, i can pass only $event, but nothing more :(

```
let link = (e, val, tas) => {
  console.log(e, val, tas);
}

function init_ovs() {
  let s = document.querySelector("#d1");

  let val = 1;
  let tas = 2;
  
  s.removeEventListener("click", link);
  s.addEventListener("click", link);
}

init_ovs();
init_ovs();
init_ovs();
init_ovs();
```

I can write let link () function inside into init_ovs, but in this case, removeEventListener is not removing event if init functions calls many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the callback logic on runtime. Better to use closure here. I have encapsulated all the handler logic inside a function which will work as a closer here. The click handler itself is calling a function referred by the variable `linkcb`. And on run time you can change the variable to point to another function. I am only changing the arguments passed during runtime.

```js
let link = (e, val, tas) => {
  console.log(e, val, tas);
}

function CreateClickHandler(elem, cb) {
    let linkcb = undefined;
    let isRegistered = false;
    let extraProps = [];
    linkcb = (e)=>{
        cb(e,...extraProps)
    }
    let handler =  (e)=>{
        linkcb(e)
    };
    return {
        bindOrUpdateHandler:  function() {
            extraProps = arguments;
            if (!isRegistered) {
                elem.addEventListener("click", handler);
                isRegistered = true;
            }
        },
        deregister:  ()=> {
            if(isRegistered){
                elem.removeEventListener("click", handler);
                isRegistered = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

let hndlr = CreateClickHandler(document.querySelector("#d1"), link);
function init_ovs() {

  let val = 1;
  let tas = 2;
  hndlr.bindOrUpdateHandler(val+Math.random(), tas+Math.random());
}
```

```html
<button id="d1">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can pass the values:

```js
let link = (e, val, tas) => {
    console.log(e, val, tas);       
  e.removeEventListener("click", linker);
}

function linker() {
    let val = 1;
    let tas = 2;

    link(this, val, tas);
}


function init_ovs() {
  let s = document.querySelector("#d1");

  s.addEventListener("click", linker);
}

init_ovs();
```

```html
<button id="d1">Val</button>
```

And you can use `once: true` to add the `eventListener` just once.

Comment: not working, second click on buttons is stops cuz  once: true

Comment: @ЕвгенийВенеград isnt that what you wanted

Comment: no ints not. The problem is, when fucntion caling 3-5 times. EventListener adding 3-5 times. And when i click once, triggering 3-5 clicks. For prevent that, need to remove, eventlistener, before addding new. But event listener can ready only link function, and in link function, i cant pass props.

Comment: You can always remove `,{once: true}`. I updated the code @ЕвгенийВенеград

Comment: And thats not work again, cuz u are not destroying event listener ) and click event adding evert time when call init ()

Comment: Do you have to use an arrow function?  Would this help? https://jsfiddle.net/2mkuqfwn/ @ЕвгенийВенеград. This is a workaround if you still want to continue using the arrow function. I also updated the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid global variables then the following would be a way to do it:

In my version `link(val,tas)` returns an event handler `function(e){...}` that will have the arguments `val` and `tas` in its scope:

```js
const link=(val,tas)=>e=>{
  console.log(e.type, val, tas);
}
document.querySelectorAll("div button").forEach((btn,i)=>
  btn.addEventListener("click",
    link(i+1,btn.textContent))
);
```

```html
<div>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>two</button><br>
<button>three</button><br>
<button>four</button>
</div>
```